# Why are there two 'for's in “she only has eyes for for a research professor”?

Tags: phrase-usage

> ‘The owner, Keenan Wynn, has got it bad for his waitress Kotty (Terry Moore), but *she only has eyes **for for** a research professor* (Frank Lovejoy).’

I've seen the sentence from [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have_got_it_bad_(or_badly)). I'm not sure if it's just a typo. I don't feel it needs two 'for's there. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the text has a printing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence in the Oxford Dictionary example:

> ‘The owner, Keenan Wynn, has got it bad for his waitress Kotty (Terry
>   Moore), but she only has eyes **for for** a research professor (Frank
>   Lovejoy).’

The repetition of 'for' is wrong, and is very probably a typing error.